# Discord.py-rewirte Log server id?

Tags: discord, discord.py

How Do I log when my bot joins the server and prints the server id?
Like so when the bot joins a server it will print the server id.

If you can give any help thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the on_guild_join event. From there you can use the guild object within the event parameters to gather the id.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.on_guild_join

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild